# Different typeblocksize in the same document with memoir

Tags: memoir, geometry

I'm writing a document with memoir class in which the table of contents has a different typeblock size than the rest of the document. I know that `geometry` package can do what I want with `\newgeometry{...} ... \restoregeometry`. The memoir manual says:

> The class also provides functions similar to those provided by the following packages, although the commands are different:
> `crop, fancyhdr, geometry, sidecap, subfigure, titlesec`.

So my question is if there is something similar to `\newgeometry{...} ... \restoregeometry` in memoir or in this case I need to load `geometry`.

Comment: What about the sentence after the one you cite: `You can use these packages if you wish, or just use the capabilities of the memoir class.`? This sounds like you can just use the geometry package.

Comment: What about the second chapter of the `memoir` manual? It says: `Although the form is different, the facilities described in this chapter are similar to those provided by the geometry package`. So this chapter will answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I just wanted to be sure that I need to load that package (I wasn’t sure to be overlooking something in the manual)

Comment: How did you alter the typeblock size for the ToC. Can you just reverse that process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know `memoir` doesn`t have equivalents to the` geometry \newgeometry`and`\restoregeometry`. However it is possible to change the layout within a` memoir` document.

```
% memlayoutprob.tex  SE 569916

\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\settypeblocksize{598pt}{341pt}{*} % the default for A4 paper
\checkandfixthelayout
\begin{document}
REGULAR LAYOUT

\lipsum[1]

CHANGE THE LAYOUT FOR THE TOC
\clearpage
\twocolumn
\settypeblocksize{400pt}{200pt}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
\onecolumn % TeX reconfigures its layout when swapping between one and two columns
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\twocolumn
\settypeblocksize{598pt}{341pt}{*} % the default for A4 paper
\checkandfixthelayout
\onecolumn
\chapter{First}
BACK TO REGULAR LAYOUT
\section{Initial}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

I know it looks a pain but it is doable. Perhaps a future version of `memoir` might include some more user-friendly code.